# AngularJS: How to display an deep object value with two ng-repeats in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access a property from a JSON object. The object is

```
$scope.people = [
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "age": "21",
        "places": {"town": "IL"},
        "work": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "name": "Christina",
        "age": "25",
        "places": {"town": "MS"},
        "work": "Designer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Luke",
        "age": "22", 
        "places": {"town": "VA"},
        "work": "Developer"
    }
]

$scope.heads = ["Name", "Age", "Work", "Town"]
$scope.attrs = ["name", "age", "work", "places.town"]
```

I want to access the places property. Here's the HTML I am using:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="head in heads">{{ head }}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person[attr] }} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Name        Age        Work          Town
-------------------------------------------------
Adam        21         Manager       IL
Christina   25         Designer      MS
Luke        22         Developer     VA
```

Everything except the town field is working properly.

Comment: I would also like to know, how do I access the data if there is more than two or three levels nesting

Comment: You need to flatten your object, [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/nzp32ks1/1/)

Comment: Hey @George! the fiddle isnt working

Comment: Try it again now

Comment: In your case instead of doing nested `ng-repeat` you can make a filter in which  you can check if the attribute exists.

Comment: If library is allowed, you can use lodash _.get

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got it working!

Comment: For me your json model is wired, are you sure the backend will give you a pattern like that?!

Comment: @CarnaruValentin I created that model for example. The data backend provides is a lot more nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a value from an object calling `person["places.town"]`. The right way to get the value is `person["places"]["town"]`.

So I advise you to create a function in the the scope that return the right property. Example:

```
$scope.getValue = function(persion, property) {

    if (property.indexOf('.') == -1) return person[property];

    var p = property.split('.');

    return person[p[0]][p[1]];

}
```

Use it in the ng-repeat like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ getValue(person, attr) }} </td>
```

You can improve the function to let it be more dynamic too.

Comment: This works when the data is one level deep, If I try to access deeper level data, it fails! Any ideas for improvement? Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: If you have deeper levels, you can use the eval function instead of the split part. Ex. return eval("person." + property);